# Reorganizing data from a dictionary in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am starting to work in `JavaScript` and I am trying out some basic stuff, so I came to a problem.
This is my `dictionary`

```
var dic = {
    'a':  {1:'alpha', 2:'beta', 3:'delta'},
    'b' : {1:1, 2:2000, 3:50},
    'c' : {1:-9, 2:2500, 3:51},
    'd' : {1:3, 2:-1000, 3:56},
    'e' : {1:-4, 2:2005, 3:-44}, 
}
```

So, I want to re-order the data so that in the end I have a dictionary like this

```
var sol = {
   'alpha' : [1, -9, 3, -4],  
   'beta' : [2000, 2500, -1000, 2005],
   'delta' : [50, 51, 56, -44], 
}
```

So I have as keys the values from `a` in `dic` and then based on which index `a` has the respective values from `b,c,d,e` are taken and put into an array.

This is what I started doing:

```
for(var i = 0; i<Object.keys(dic).length;i++){ 
    for(var j=0; j<Object.keys(dic['a']).length; j++){
      console.log(dic[i][j])
    }
}
```

But then I saw that I can't really access the info with `dic[i][j]` and I got completly lost.

Could anyone give me some tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're on the right path in iterating.  If you iterate through the object with a for/in , you can see you will have all the info you need:

```
let i = 1;
for (let x in dic) {
     console.log(dic[x][i])
     i++
}
```

so the first iteration will give you:

```
for (let x in dic) {
     console.log(dic[x][1])
}
```

Console shows:

```
// alpha
// 1
// -9
// 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using object destructing assignment with various ES6 Array functions:

```js
const dic = {
    'a': { 1: 'alpha', 2: 'beta', 3: 'delta' },
    'b': { 1: 1, 2: 2000, 3: 50 },
    'c': { 1: -9, 2: 2500, 3: 51 },
    'd': { 1: 3, 2: -1000, 3: 56 },
    'e': { 1: -4, 2: 2005, 3: -44 },
}

const { a: keys, ...values } = dic;

const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(keys).map(
  ([index, key]) => [key, Object.values(values).map(value => value[index])]
));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I'm slow to post, but this will provide what you are looking for...

```js
var dic = {
  'a': {
    1: 'alpha',
    2: 'beta',
    3: 'delta'
  },
  'b': {
    1: 1,
    2: 2000,
    3: 50
  },
  'c': {
    1: -9,
    2: 2500,
    3: 51
  },
  'd': {
    1: 3,
    2: -1000,
    3: 56
  },
  'e': {
    1: -4,
    2: 2005,
    3: -44
  },
}

var dicKeys = Object.keys(dic);
var sol = {};
var newKeyList = Object.keys(dic.a);
var newValueList = Object.values(dic.a);
for (var newIndex = 0; newIndex < newKeyList.length; newIndex++) {
  var newKey = newKeyList[newIndex];
  var newValue = newValueList[newIndex];
  sol[newValue] = [];
  dicKeys.forEach(function(key) {
      if (key == 'a') {
        return;
      }
      sol[newValue].push(dic[key][newKey]);
  });
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(sol));
```